# Passing parameters to another JSP file using <jsp:include> tag

Tags: jsp, include, jstl

I have a JSP file and in that file I am including another JSP file:

```
<c:forEach var="instanceVar" items="${instanceList}">
    <c:set var="instance"><jsp:include page="instance.jsp"/></c:set>
    ...
</c:forEach
```

In the file *instance.jsp* I want to use a variable `instanceVar`. I want to do it using JSTL. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
<c:forEach var="instanceVar" items="${instanceList}">
    <jsp:include page="instance.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="myVar" value="${instanceVar}"/>
    </jsp:include>
</c:forEach>
```

In the `instance.jsp`

```
<c:out value="${param.myVar}"/>
```

Comment: And how can I access the param.myVar in the java code in the included jsp, please?

Comment: The question was about JSTL. And it is better not to mix java code with JSTL.

Comment: It worked*. but in my case, I wasn't allowed to pass a list.
The jsp complier raise an error saying which the params has to be static (value="some static value").

Is not to downvote it but it didn't solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative would be using `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()`

Comment: @SpringLearner `setAttribute()` of `HttpSession` or `HttpServletRequest`?

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is using JSTL tag c:set and request scope.

```
<c:set var="instance" value="${your.value}" scope="request"/>
<jsp:include page="instance.jsp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that work for me is the following

```
<c:set var="instance" value="${semaforoData}" scope="request"/>
<jsp:include page="semaforo.jsp"/>
```

in the jsp file, the code is:

```
<c:forEach var='itemSemaforo' items='${semaforoData}' varStatus='loopSemaforo'>
Print data
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Worked for me and give me the chance to pass any kind of dynamic objects.

It don't pass really the parameters, but, create a variable in the page/backing class which can be used in the included jsp.