# include another jsp which is dynamically loaded by a param

Tags: jsp

i am new to jsp and i 'm not a English native speaker. very appreciate if u could give me some help.
**My question is:** i have a jsp which uses easyui layout dividing into two parts.
on the left ,there is a navigate part, i use 'for' loops creating some links.
`<% 
  for(Integer latestContactID :newMsgDao(conn).getLatestContacts(user.getID())){
      out.println("<li><a href = \"#\">"+ 
     new UserDao(conn).getUserByID(latestContactID).getUserName() +"</a></li>");}
%>`
**i wish** when i click on the 'a' link, i could include another jsp on the right side of this jsp dynamically loaded according to 'latesetContactID' .it means i need to pass the 'latestContactID' param to the included jsp.
what should i do? THANKS!

Comment: Are talking about   http://www.jeasyui.com/index.php    ? Is that what you are using?

Comment: right. finally i use jquery.load and pass the value by' para' of  '<a>'

Answer (score 0):

```
<jsp:include page="(name)jsp">


    <jsp:param name="myVar" value="${instanceVar}"/>


</jsp:include>
```

In the jsp

Please refer this : [Passing parameters to another JSP file using <jsp:include> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150683/passing-parameters-to-another-jsp-file-using-jspinclude-tag)