# jsp insertAttribute pass parameter to tiles

Tags: jsp, tiles

i hate that bad documentation... i loose so much time in googling how basic things get work... ok, here is my problem:

I have a list of objects which are iterated in the jsp... in every iteration i want to insert a "sub-jsp" and pass the current object to this jsp....

tiles-definition: (version 3.0.5)

```
<definition name="projectAdmin/execAproject" extends="defaultTemplate">  
       <put-attribute name="title" value="Projekt-Design" />  
       <put-attribute name="body" >
        <definition template="/WEB-INF/projectAdmin/execAproject.jsp">
            <put-attribute cascade="true" name="subCustomItem_form" value="/WEB-INF/projectAdmin/subCustomItem_form.jsp" />  
        </definition>
       </put-attribute>
   </definition>
```

execAproject.jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item" varStatus="theCount">
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="subCustomItem_form" >
        <tiles:putAttribute name="super_name" value="bla" />
    </tiles:insertAttribute>
</c:forEach>
```

subCustomItem_form.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <div class="custom_item_form">
        Custom-Item ${super_name}
    </div>
```

As you can see, i iterate the list of items... and in each iteration step the "subCustomItem_form.jsp" is "included". I also tried to pass the variable/parameter "super_name" but it doesn't work.

**The Problem**

The problem is, that the variable "super_name" is never displayed in "subCustomItem_form.jsp". I don't have any errors or debug-msg or something like this. The jsp "subCustomItem_form.jsp" is displayed, but not the variable.

**The Question**

How do i pass a variable? In this case the variable "super_name". (later i want to pass the item-object.

Thank's for help!

**EDIT**
I solved the problem a bit... Ok, now i was able to access to variable "super_name" in the jsp "subCustomItem_form.jsp". Therefor i only change the way to access to that variable:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
    <div class="custom_item_form">
        Custom-Item <tiles:getAsString name="super_name"/>
    </div>
```

If I understand the problem/solution correctly then my mistake was that i have a variable in a "jsp"-context or pagecontext, but not as a JSTL-variable... but at that point i do some stuff like  I "changed" the variable from jsp to a JSTL-"context"... so i have to access the variable in a JSTL-way... I know my description is not so good formulated, but i hope you can understand me...In that way i was able to pass a string variable. But I'm still not able to pass or access an object.

**Now the current Problem/Question**
How do i pass an object and access this object in this way "${object.variable} or do i have to write the object in a context-object? Is it possible to access a object in the JSTL-way?

I Hope you can help me!

V

Comment: As a suggestion, you can move the solution that you found into the answer section. You are allowed to self-answer if you found the problem on your own if no one else helped you can accept your own self-answer. Moving the answer into the answer section will make it easier for future users to read.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**The Solution**

Ok, I finally get it done... I tried to find a way only with JSP without using JSTL.... There i found the following link: [Passing parameters to another JSP file using <jsp:include> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150683/passing-parameters-to-another-jsp-file-using-jspinclude-tag)
There is the solution descriped, so that i changed the code of the "execAproject.jsp" as follows:

```
<c:if test="${item.projStepItem.item_type eq 'customItem'}">
    <div>
        <c:set var="super_name" value="${item}" scope="request"/>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="subCustomItem_form" />
    </div>
</c:if>
```

Ok if i unterstand the solution correctly does the "c:set"-line set the variable in the request-scope,so that i can access the variable in the sub-jsp like a variable that is given by the backend at a request. That's why it's also important to the variable in the request-scope.
The documentation of all these is rather bad, in my opinion, so i hope that helps anyone with a similar problem.

Have a nice day.

V