# Send and include JSP dynamically in another JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, include

I currently have a Jsp called menu-container that loads a base menu that should appear on each of my pages, but each page will add options to that menu, those options go in a specific place, so I would like to know how I can send the Content to the menu-container (which is a Jsp) from another, here is the menu-container:

```
<ul id="menu">
 <!-- Modificar las authorities segun la aplicacion -->
 <div class="navbar navbar-default menu">
  <div class="navbar-header" >
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
             data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-colapse" aria-
 expanded="false"
              aria-controls="navbar">
             <span class="sr-only">Menú</span> <span class="icon-bar">
 </span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<!-- Menu colapse -->
<div id="menu-colapse" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<!-- Menu usuario - para opciones de control del usuario-->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown user-options">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
            <!--[if IE 7]>
                Opciones <span class="caret"></span>
            <![endif]-->
        </a>
        <!-- En este dropdown van las opciones que se necesiten en la aplicacion -->
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

            <!-- Nombre del usuario, recuperado por spring -->
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="a-no-link">
                    <!--[if !IE 7]><!-->
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-padding-6 fix-right-menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                    <sec:authentication property="principal" />
                </a>
            </li>

            <!-- Logout -->
            <li>
                <div class="form-inline" style="color: white !important; height: 23px;">
                <!--[if !IE 7]><!-->
                            <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-padding-6" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left: 16px;"></i>
                        <!--<![endif]-->
                <a  href="SalirAplicacion" style="color: white !important;"><spring:message code="menuPpal.salir"/></a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul> 
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown user-options">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-language"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="a-link" href="configuracionInicio?idioma=en&pagina=inicio" title="English">English</a></li>
            <li><a class="a-link" href="configuracionInicio?idioma=es&pagina=inicio" title="Español">Español</a></li>
            <li><a class="a-link" href="configuracionInicio?idioma=fr&pagina=inicio" title="Français">Français</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- /Menu usuario -->

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" aria-expanded="false" id="main-menu">


    //This is the place for the Li Items 
    //One or more items to add


</ul>
```

Now the invoking Jsp has something like this:

```
 <jsp:include page="comun/menu-container.jsp" />
```

But as I must send it from the jsp that invokes the items (from which it invokes because it is in that they are distinguished from each other of course), but I do not know how to do it, suppose I put them in a new Jsp, that I call it and then How do I pass it to the container? And how do you receive it?

Thanks for taking the time any help is welcome, regards!

Pdta: what I want to avoid is having to have muuuchas classes menu that only change in what they add because it makes me very bad practice.

Comment: Your question is bit unclear for me. Check the answer I have posted. Please let me know if this is not what you want to do, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameters to another JSP file using <jsp:include> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150683/passing-parameters-to-another-jsp-file-using-jspinclude-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass extra menu item as parameters from invoking JSP.

**menu-container.jsp**

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    ${param.menuItems}
</ul>
```

**invoking_jsp.jsp**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Invoking JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="menu-container.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="menuItems" value="<li>Special menu item 1</li><li>Special menu item 2</li>"/>
    </jsp:include>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Edit** : if you want to keep the menu items in a separate jsp page, as you suggest in the comments, you can just pass the jsp page name as the parameter as below.

**menu-container.jsp**

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <jsp:include page="${param.menuItems}"/>
</ul>
```

**invoking_jsp.jsp**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Invoking JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="menu-container.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="menuItems" value="menuPrincipal.jsp"/>
    </jsp:include>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can i do something like this:    <jsp:include page="${baseURL}/comun/menu-container.jsp">
          <jsp:param name="menuItems" value='<jsp:include page="${baseURL}/menus/menuPrincipal.jsp"/>' />
 </jsp:include>

Comment: @jaxonjma You cant do that, but you can pass the JSP page name and include it in the target JSP page. check the edited answer. Accept the answer if your problem is resolved.

Comment: Thank you @Chathura Buddhika that is perfect!

Comment: @jaxonjma Pass another parameter to identify whether it is raw html or jsp page name. In menu-container.jsp page, you can check for that parameter and insert the correct code using if/else

Comment: @ Chathura Buddhika  Could you give a look at this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866312/running-job-in-java-from-sql-server