# How do I change the code for an included jsp file on a different page

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, jsp

I include a jsp file onto an another **jsp** file but here I would like to change the included file just a little bit specific for the current page.

a.jsp is included on b.jsp
Now I want to make changes to a.jsp specific for b.jsp

Comment: Are you planning to perform these changes on the client side, using javascript? If yes, act like there has been no nesting at all. The rendered output is just a html page, containing everything.

Comment: If you're not using `<%@include>` but something like `<jsp:include>`, you could add parameters to your template which can be evaluated and perform "magical" changes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150683/passing-parameters-to-another-jsp-file-using-jspinclude-tag for more.

Comment: thanks for the help, What I did was, I gave ids to divisions in the file which was to be included and using jQuery made changes by adding and removing classes.